# Как оптимизировать код (dart, flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Есть приложение где происходит роутинг между страницами. Сами странички очень типичные. Интересует как можно оптимизировать код чтобы не повторять его какждой странице. Там отличаются всего неcколько значений. У всех переменных на каждой странице название в зависимости от ее номера: buttonText1, _MyCustomFormState1 и тд.

Я пометил !!!ОТЛИЧАЕТСЯ!!! то что кардинально отличается. Я бы это все запихнул в функцию, где на входе отличающиеся элементы, но не понятно как это делать с виджетами...

Буду благодарен за любую наводку.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:math/settings.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String text1;
int _coins1 = 0;
final UnitId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
const String testDevice = "8C804F944FA76E19B25112CFF43BED32";
String buttonText1 = "Подсказка";
Color buttonColor1 = Colors.blue;


class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomFormState1 createState() => _MyCustomFormState1();
}


class _MyCustomFormState1 extends State<FirstRoute> {
  static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
      testDevices: testDevice != null ? <String>[testDevice] : null,
      nonPersonalizedAds: true,
      keywords: <String>['Game']);

  Future<bool> internet() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    getCredential();

    FirebaseAdMob.instance
        .initialize(appId: 'ca-app-pub-9594082506249372~8751878673');

    RewardedVideoAd.instance.listener =
        (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {

      if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.loaded) {
        RewardedVideoAd.instance.show();
        setState(() {
          MyOverlay.hide();
        });
      }

      if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
        setState(() {
          MyOverlay.hide();
        });
      }

      if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {
        setState(() {
          if (_coins1 >= 10) {
            buttonText1 = "Решение";
            buttonColor1 = Colors.green;
            _coins1 += rewardAmount;
            showDialog(
              //barrierDismissible: false,
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => _Reshenie(context),
            );
          }

          if (_coins1 == 0) {
            buttonText1 = "Решение";
            buttonColor1 = Colors.green;
            _coins1 += rewardAmount;
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => _Podskazka(context),
            );
          }
        });
      }
    };
    super.initState();
  }

  final myController1 = TextEditingController();
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1;


  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController1.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onChanged(String text) async {
    sharedPreferences1 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences1.setString("level", text);
    getCredential();
  }

  getCredential() async {
    sharedPreferences1 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      text1 = sharedPreferences1.getString("level");
    });
  }

  Widget _Reshenie(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Решение'),
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      content: new Image.asset(
        "assets/images/1_1.jpg", !!!ОТЛИЧАЕТСЯ!!!
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          textColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          label: Text('Все понятно'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _Podskazka(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Подсказка'),
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      content: Text('+',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 65)),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          textColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          //`Icon` to display
          label: Text('Все понятно'),
          //`Text` to display
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          return Future.value(false);
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('MATH'),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, "/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Image.asset('assets/images/1.jpg'),!!!ОТЛИЧАЕТСЯ!!!
                  new TextField(
                      controller: myController1,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      autofocus: false,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: 'Введите ответ',
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 14.0, bottom: 8.0, top: 8.0),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                          ))),
                  FlatButton.icon(
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                    color: buttonColor1,
                    splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                    textColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                    label: Text(buttonText1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                    onPressed: () {

                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

                      internet().then((result) {
                        if (result == false) {
                          MyOverlay.hide();
                          setState(() {
                            if (_coins1 >= 10) {
                              buttonText1 = "Решение";
                              buttonColor1 = Colors.green;
                              _coins1 += 10;
                              showDialog(
                                //barrierDismissible: false,
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    _Reshenie(context),
                              );
                            }

                            if (_coins1 == 0) {
                              buttonText1 = "Решение";
                              buttonColor1 = Colors.green;
                              _coins1 += 10;
                              showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    _Podskazka(context),
                              );
                            }
                          });
                        } else {
                          if (_coins1 < 10) {
                            MyOverlay.show(context);
                            RewardedVideoAd.instance.load(
                                adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId,
                                targetingInfo: targetingInfo);
                          }

                          if (_coins1 == 10) {
                            MyOverlay.show(context);
                            RewardedVideoAd.instance.load(
                                adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId,
                                targetingInfo: targetingInfo);
                            setState(() {
                              buttonColor1 = Colors.green;
                              buttonText1 = "Решение";
                            });
                          }

                          if (_coins1 > 10) {
                            setState(() {
                              buttonColor1 = Colors.green;
                              buttonText1 = "Решение";
                            });
                            showDialog(
                                //barrierDismissible: false,
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    _Reshenie(context));
                          }
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              label: Text('Ответ',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 16, decoration: TextDecoration.none)),

              onPressed: () {
                if (myController1.text == "7") { !!!ОТЛИЧАЕТСЯ!!!
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    barrierDismissible: false,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Container(
                          height: 75.0,
                          width: 60.0,
                          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.check_circle,
                                color: Colors.greenAccent.shade400, size: 50.0),
                            Text("Правильно")
                          ]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                  _onChanged("2");!!!ОТЛИЧАЕТСЯ!!!
                  setState(() {
                    _coins1 = 0;
                  });
                  new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2),
                      () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/" + text1));
                } else {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          content: Container(
                            height: 75.0,
                            width: 60.0,
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.cancel,
                                  color: Colors.deepOrange.shade400,
                                  size: 50.0),
                              Text("Неправильно")
                            ]),
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton.icon(
                              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                              textColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                              label: Text('Закрыть'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                }
              },
              tooltip: 'Отправить ответ',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              icon: Icon(Icons.check)),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажу на более легком примере.

Как было:

```
MyWidget(),

...

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("123"), // !!!ОТЛИЧАЕТСЯ!!!
    );
  }
}
```

Стало:

```
MyWidget("123")

...

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  MyWidget(this.text);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.text),
    );
  }
}
```

Что произошло: мы добавили поле, которое инициализируется в конструкторе класса. Данное поле обязательно должно быть `final`. И получаем данные через `widget`.

Также бывает, что нам нужно инициализировать не все поля, для этого можно сделать так:

```
MyWidget("123") // или так MyWidget("123", number: 1)

...

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int number;
  final String text;

  MyWidget(this.text, {this.number});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}
```

---

Попробовать можно в [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/), а еще попробуйте удалить `, n: "zero"`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget("123", 10, n: "zero"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final int num;
  final String n;

  MyWidget(this.text, this.num, {this.n});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: [
        Text(widget.text),
        Text(widget.num.toString()),
        Text(widget.n ?? "null"),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: А если я хочу сделать виджет с несколькими значениями? MyWidget("1", "1.png", "33") Как мне их получить? Просто тут не видно четкой структуры как в функциях ($var1, $var2, $var3)

Comment: @АлексейБондарь самый последний примеры, только убрать фигурные скобки. Вы можете добавлять сколько угодно final полей и присваивать их в конструкторе этого класса. Сам конструктор даёт четкую структуру.

Comment: MyWidget("123", 1, "1.png"); А как потом их выловить? Что-то не пойму хоть убей:)

Comment: Или нужно так MyWidget(text: "123", number: 1, img: "1.png") ?

Comment: @АлексейБондарь по final полям, они будут иметь значения которые вы отправите в конструктор. Посмотрите код "стало" а именно Text(widget.text),

Comment: Можете на каком-то коротком рабочем примере показать? Я выше прикрепил скрин - вылезли пару ошибок.

Comment: @АлексейБондарь добавил, самый последний пример

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!